# How to create function in Python 2.6

Tags: python

As being a newbie python learning fellow, I have created the below script to check the various process and Filesystem usage, Which i would like to be in a more sophisticated or best fashioned way wrapping into the functions..

Please suggest the way to do it..
My python version is 2.6

## cat healthCheck.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python
    import subprocess
    import socket
    THRESHOLD = 90

    HST = (socket.gethostname())
    print "HostName:", HST
    PSNTP = subprocess.call('ps -e| grep ntp > /dev/null 2>&1', shell=True)
    if PSNTP == 0:
        print "Service Status:  NTP Service is Running"
    else:
       print  "Service Status:  NTP Service is Running"

    PSNSCD = subprocess.call('ps -e | grep nscd > /dev/null 2>&1', shell=True)
    if PSNSCD == 0:
       print "Service Status:  NSCD Service is Running On the host" , HST
    else:
       print "Service Status:  NSCD Service Not is Running", HST

    PSMAIL = subprocess.call('ps -e | grep sendmail> /dev/null 2>&1', shell=True)
    if PSMAIL == 0:
       print "Service Status:  Sendmail Service is Running"
    else:
       print "Service Status:  Sendmail is Not Service Not is Running"

    PSALTRIS = subprocess.call('ps -e | grep aex-plug > /dev/null 2>&1', shell=True)
    if PSALTRIS == 0:
       print "Service Status:  Altris Service is Running"
    else:
       print "Service Status:  Altris Service Not is Running"

    PSAUTMNT = subprocess.call('ps -e| grep automount > /dev/null 2>&1', shell=True)
    if PSAUTMNT == 0:
       print "Service Status:  Automount Service is Running"
    else:
       print "Service Status:  Automont Service Not is Running"

    rootfs = subprocess.Popen(['df', '-h', '/'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    output = rootfs.communicate()[0].strip().split("\n")
    for x in output[1:]:
        if int(x.split()[-2][:-1]) >= THRESHOLD:
            print "Service Status: Filesystem For Root(/) is more than 20 % On the Host" , HST
        else:
            print "Service Status: Filesystem For Root(/) is Normal on The Host", HST

    varfs = subprocess.Popen(['df', '-h', '/'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    output = varfs.communicate()[0].strip().split("\n")
    for x in output[1:]:
        if int(x.split()[-2][:-1]) >= THRESHOLD:
            print "Service Status: Filesystem For /var is more than 20 % On the Host" , HST
        else:
            print "Service Status: Filesystem For /var  is Normal on The Host", HST
```

Comment: Such kind of questions are more suited for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: No. We are not here to tell you how to create a function when that information is just one google search away.

Comment: @timegeb.    Nice to have your opinion, that I'm surely looking.

Answer (score 1):

@timgeb has a really good point. What you're looking for is as simple as Googling what a function is and then spending some time reading.

That being said, a couple of pointers, realise that you're asking for people's time here so it's far better you understand the etiquette. First you've posted a problem without seemingly having done any research, at least you haven't hinted anything to the contrary. It's far better to provide examples of what you've tried and let us know your thinking so we can point you in the right direction rather than figuratively saying "I want my code to be more sophisticated but I want all of you to do the work for me".

That being said, here's something to get you going. In terms of functions it's about writing repetitive code once so that you don't have to do it again and again. A simple example from above, you wrote " = subprocess.call('ps -e | grep nscd > /dev/null 2>&1', shell=True)" several times, apart from nscd everything else remains the same, therefore:

```
def call_function(service):
   return subprocess.call('ps -e | grep service > /dev/null 2>&1', shell=True)

PSNTP = call_function("ntp")
PSNSCD = call_function("nscd")

if PSNTP == 0:
........
```

Make sense? If something in the command "ps -e......." changes then you only need to change it one time rather than searching through your whole program to change it many places.

Comment: appreciate your & everyone's time, coming to your point:
`realise that you're asking for people's time here so it's far better you understand the etiquette.` No, i didn't ask someone to Kill their time rather just asked for Suggestions, I'm already going through the google materials and whatsoever i can learn best, I tried this code by learning out here myself, I understand , time is crucial for everyone now a days and that's the way i appreciated the @timgeb idea.

Comment: I understand the etiquette that really not required to learn , if someone can't give his/her opinion then he/she need not to even bother about giving the sarcastic comments at all. This world is full of examples where our very high minded peoples given the brightest teaching to the world without being selfish at all like , Dennis ritchei where all we are standing and feeling ourslelf so called experts, he even not bother to share a single bit of information to world we should follow his ideals not merely a haughty on placing an idea this make sense to me!!